# How can I modify event data on dev/input/event#?

Tags: c++, events, input, touchscreen

I want to modify event touchscreen data from dev/input/event# by doing following, but not success. Can any help?

- Open dev/input/event# with RDWR permission
- Use ioctl with EVIOCGRAB to grab event data
- Read data from /dev/input/event#. Everything is good
- Under some conditions, modify event values, then write back to same /dev/input/event#.

Problem

- The write is good, but it is grabbed by my program. If I grab and un-grab (EVIOCGRAB with NULL), then both(all) events data, original and new data, will pass to my desktop.

Question:

- How can I grab event data, remove it from dev/input/event# queue, then write new data back to a same dev/input/event#, then un-grab ?

Comment: I am wondering the same. Did you figure this out?